# Pandas, numpy: return multiple columns in `np.select`?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the following DataFrame.

```
    A   B
0   1.0 4
1   2.0 5
2   NaN 6
```

I want to turn it into the following dataframe.

```
    A   B   val val_source
0   1.0 4   1.0 A
1   2.0 5   2.0 A
2   NaN 6   6.0 B
```

What's the easiest way to do this? I envision an `np.select` that returns multiple columns, something like

```
conds = [df['A'].notna(), True]
choices = [df[['A']].assign(val_source='A'), df[['B']].assign(val_source='B')]
df[['val', 'val_source']] = np.select(conds, choices)
```

but this results in an error. I'm forced to do two separate `np.select` statements, even though they share the same `conds`.

```
conds = [df['A'].notna(), True]
_choices_val_src = [
    (df['A'], 'A'),
    (df['B'], 'B'),
]
choices_val, choices_src = zip(*_choices_val_src)
df['val'] = np.select(conds, choices_val, default=np.nan)
df['val_source'] = np.select(conds, choices_src, default=np.nan)
```

Is there a cleaner way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Use subsetting/indexing as shown below:

```
idx = df.notna().to_numpy().argmax(1)
df['val'] = df.to_numpy()[(df.index, idx)]
df['val_source'] = df.columns[idx]
df
     A  B  val val_source
0  1.0  4  1.0          A
1  2.0  5  2.0          A
2  NaN  6  6.0          B
```

Comment: Why the parentheses on `(df.index, idx)` when they don't do anything?

Comment: `df.index` can be generalized to `np.arange(len(df))`

Comment: Worth noting this resembles the example in the user guide at [Looking up values by index/column labels](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs//user_guide/indexing.html#looking-up-values-by-index-column-labels)

Answer (score 1):

For this particular set of conditions, you can also change the approach: [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and [`groupby.first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.first.html).

```
df[['val_source', 'val']] = df.stack().reset_index(1).groupby(level=0).first()
```

Output:

```
     A  B val_source  val
0  1.0  4          A  1.0
1  2.0  5          A  2.0
2  NaN  6          B  6.0
```

Or since you only have two conditions to choose from:

```
m = df['A'].notna()
df['val'] = df['A'].where(m, df['B'])
df['val_source'] = np.where(m, 'A', 'B')
```

Output:

```
     A  B  val val_source
0  1.0  4  1.0          A
1  2.0  5  2.0          A
2  NaN  6  6.0          B
```

Comment: This was the exact way I was going to do this problem then I distracted with a "honey-do".